# How to execute two ffmpeg commands sequentially

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, event-handling

I'm using this library [FFmpeg-Android](https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android) to run FFmpeg in my Android project.

I have this code with two different commands I want to run simultaneously:

```
private void FFmpegExecuteTask() {
    try {

        String[] command1 = {
                "-i",
                mInputFile.getAbsolutePath(),
                "-c",
                "copy",
                "-bsf:v",
                "h264_mp4toannexb",
                "-f",
                "mpegts",
                "-y",
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "temp1.ts",
                "-i",
                mIntro.getAbsolutePath(),
                "-c",
                "copy",
                "-bsf:v",
                "h264_mp4toannexb",
                "-f",
                "mpegts",
                "-y",
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "temp2.ts"
        };

        String[] command2 = {
                "-i",
                "concat:" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "temp1.ts|" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "temp2.ts",
                "-c",
                "copy",
                "-bsf:a",
                "aac_adtstoasc",
                "-y",
                mOutputFile.getAbsolutePath()
        };

        final FFtask task = mFFmpeg.execute(command1, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.d(TAG, "on start");
                progressDialog.setMessage("Processing...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.d(TAG, "on finish");
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                Log.d(TAG, message);
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                showVideoPreview();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {
                Log.d(TAG, message);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Processing\n" + message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                Log.e(TAG, message);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "command already running");
    }
}
```

I want to execute command1 first and then command2.

Command1 executes well but when onSuccess and when onFinish command1 I want to run command2 after that.

Is there any possibility of executing several FFmpeg commands sequentially and once all of them have successfully finished calling a method for handling the results?

Comment: I want to do something like that! have you find any solution??

Comment: @JayPatel Not yet, but what I did was call FFmpegExecuteTask again within onFinish() and change the command. It is not an elegant solution but it works

Comment: Yeah I did the same thing!

Comment: @JayPatel got any solution?